# Drawing Contours using customize Sequence points?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working with OpenCV to find the contour area of an image using cvFindContours(). Then, I would like to Draw this contour with different coordinates (and different pixels correspondence) ...

So, I get all contours element points using cvGetSeqElem() and convert pixels correspondence and create customized cvSeq and load each element to the customized cvSeq. However, when I try to Draw contour with customized cvSeq there are no responses in the image.

For the purpose of this work I would like to use the contour for masking image.

Code is like this:

```
<!-- language: c++ -->

CvMemStorage *memStorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* seq = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint), memStorage);

void  SetMaskingPoints(CvPoint point)
{ cvSeqPush(seq, &regionPoint); }
void DrawMaskingPoints()
{ cvDrawContours(maskingImage, seq, cvScalar(255,255,255), cvScalar(0,0,0), 0, 1, 8); }
```

My code starts with getting contour element and load to SetMaskingPoints() as sequentially,  then Draw contour by DrawMasingPoints().

I also tried to printout and found that cvSeq consists of points value, but cannot be drawn.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `0` in `cvCreateSeq` with this: `(CV_SEQ_KIND_CURVE|CV_SEQ_ELTYPE_POINT|CV_SEQ_FLAG_CLOSED)`.